# how to determine state of DB_DataObject instance?

Tags: php, oop, pear

As I add methods to various DB_DataObject classes, I lean towards

```
Class Example extends DB_DataObject {
function methodx() //start fresh
{
    $newObject = DB_DataObject::factory($this->__table);
    /* do stuff with $newObject */
}
```

rather than

```
function methodx() //use current instance
{
    /* do stuff with $this */
}
```

I've realized I do this because I don't know how to determine the state of $this. The calling code might have done any of the following:

```
$e = DB_DataObject::factory('Example'); $e->get(16); $e->methodx();
$e = DB_DataObject::factory('Example'); $e->somekey=$value; $e->methodx();
$e = DB_DataObject::factory('Example'); $e->somekey=$value; $e->find(); $e->methodx();
```

How can I determine the state of "$this" when I get my hands on it?

Are there rules of thumb or design for using the current instance vs. creating a new instance of the class?

Comment: I don't think the question as general/generic as it is can be answered to your satisfaction. It greatly depends on how methodx() depends on/interacts with the state of the object.

Comment: Thanks, and fair point. But on my first question: how would methodx determine whether $this is a clean instance (essentially a row in the database) or a find "set up" (where ->find() would be an appropriate next step) or a fetch "set up"(ditto for "fetch").

Comment: It don't, at least not any more than `== null` i'd guess. Your object should not have any data if it's a fresh instance (if I understand your code/question). Edit; I'm sorry - just saw the date on this question.

Answer (score 0):

If your method requires a "clean state" (class variables set to their default values), then simply create a new instance.

All you would save is a object instantiation, which is cheap.

---

You could determine if the state changed by using `[ReflectionClass::getDefaultProperties()][1]` and comparing them with the current property values. And then you'd have to check if any new properties have been added dynamically.

Alternatively, create a new instance and compare all properties with the current one :)